# MySQL database insertion error

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project to upload images into a directory and store image paths in database table. The image upload work fine but my text input for name is not working. I need your help.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{

$path=$path.$_FILES['file_upload']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'],$path))
{
echo " ".basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name'])." has been uploaded<br/>";
echo '<img src="gallery/'.$_FILES['file_upload']['name'].'" width="48" height="48"/>';
$img=$_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
    $query="insert into imgtables (name,imgurl,date) values('$name',STR_TO_DATE('$dateofbirth','%d-%m-%y'),'$img',now())";
    if($sp->query($query)){
     echo "<br/>Inserted to DB also";   
    }else{
        echo "Error <br/>".$sp->error;       
    }
}
else
{
echo "There is an error,please retry or ckeck path";
}
}

?>
```

The form is as follows:

```
<form action="gallery.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="384" border="1" align="center">

<tr>
<td width="108">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="108">Select File</td>
<td width="260"><label><input type="file" name="file_upload"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><label><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File"></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You should take a look at the mysql error message.

Comment: When I echo($query) there is no error indicated since some columns (imgurl and date) are successfully populated, except for one column called name.

Comment: And where do you set `$name`? It's not set in the provided code sample (unless `register_globals` is on, but that would be rather bad ...).

Comment: where have you defined ur $name ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the variable `$name` is empty or undefined and this is why all the other columns are populated and not this one.  Also since the query is valid you don't get any error.

You can confirm this with a simple :

```
echo($name);
```

**Not related to your problem :**

- Your code seems vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25811874/1980659) : use [prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1980659) to prevent this.
- Is `register_globals` turned on?  If so you should really consider turning it off.  To know why, have a look at [Why is REGISTER_GLOBALS so bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1417373/1980659).

Comment: Thank you. I isset the variables and now it's working. But, I need to prepared statement now. Regards